# Error message when running panelAR package in R

Tags: r

"I am trying to use the panelAR package for a Panel Regression model with AR(1) correction and panel-corrected standard errors. The package has several arguments however when I run the model I receive an error "Error: The time variable must be defined as an integer". Even though the time variable "year" is st as an integer".

It's probably a simple fix but would appreciate any helpful advice. Thanks

data$year <-as.integer(data$year)
data$area <-as.integer(data$area)
str(data)

```
corrmodel <- panelAR(crmrte ~density+pctymle+pctclaims+rdcrte+antrte+pctleavFE+
                pctleavHE+pctleavEMP+pctleavUn, data= pdata, panelVar = "area", 
                timeVar = "year", autoCorr = "ar1", panelCorrMethod = "pcse",
                rhotype = "breg",bound.rho = FALSE,rho.na.rm = FALSE, 
                panel.weight = "t-1",dof.correction = FALSE,complete.case = FALSE,
                seq.times = FALSE, singular.ok=TRUE)
```

[R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/panelAR/versions/0.1/topics/panelAR)

Comment: Is your data.frame named `data` or `pdata` (your data argument)?

Comment: sorry, I have tried it on "pdata" and original "data". in both data frames the "year" variable is set as an integer, however the error still persists?

Answer (score 1):

For posterity: Apparently `panelAR` doesn't like `tibbles/tbl_df`. Applying `as.data.frame()` to my input data set solved the issue as noted here: https://github.com/kkashin/panelAR/issues/2